# What is the geometric interpretation of the norm of a log-quaternion?

Tags: geometry, rotations, quaternions

Suppose I have two rotation matrices $R_i$ and $R_j$, what is the geometric interpretation of the norm of the log-quaternion of $R_i\cdot R_j^T$? I only  have a very rudimentary understanding of the algebra behind quaternions.

Comment: What's the log-quaternion of a rotation matrix? Do you mean the logarithm of the (positive-real-part) quaternion representing a rotation matrix? If so, it has pretty much the same interpretation as the logarithm as a complex number, but using a different unit vector instead of $i$.